# Earth Engine featurecollection size suddenly too large to compute

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm struggling with what should be a fairly mundane process of extracting raster values to polygons in Google Earth Engine. However, I'm running into size constraints at every turn. The snippet below is a portion of longer iterative script.  In this instance, I print the size of an `ee.FeatureCollection`, which returns 2455168 features. Large, but I wouldn't call it ginormous. I then extract the maximum raster values within each polygon in the Feature Collection using the function described in this tutorial [Extracting Raster Values](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/extract-raster-values-for-points#zonalstatsfc_params_%E2%87%92_eefeaturecollection). For brevity, I haven't copied that function here, but you can see where it is called from another script. I then check the size of the resulting FeatureCollection (which should still be 2455168 features) and suddenly Earth Engine can't calculate it and throws the error:

> Number(Error)
> Computed value is too large.

I have tested a version of this code successfully on a *much* smaller area, so I am attempting to chunk it up. But to do so, I need to know the number of features in my featurecollections as I traverse each iteration of this process (not shown). So what is going on here that EE can determine the size in one instance, but then not in another?

```
    //------Building Footprints 

var objects = ee.data.listAssets('projects/sat-io/open-datasets/MSBuildings/US')['assets'].slice(0,1,1)
print(ee.FeatureCollection('projects/sat-io/open-datasets/MSBuildings/US/Alabama').size())


//------Raster Data
//--Bare Earth Elevation
var NASADEM = ee.Image('USGS/3DEP/10m')
var elevation = NASADEM.select('elevation');
var NASADEM = ee.ImageCollection([elevation]);
var elev = NASADEM.mosaic().setDefaultProjection('EPSG:3857',null,30).set("system:time_start",ee.Date('2000-01-01').millis());

//--DSM - Building/Veg heights
var glo30 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30");
var dsmelev = glo30.mosaic().setDefaultProjection('EPSG:3857',null,30).set("system:time_start",ee.Date('2000-01-01').millis())

//------Wrap the single image in an ImageCollection for use in the zonalStats function:
var topo = ee.Image.cat(elev,dsmelev).set('system:time_start', ee.Date('2000-01-01').millis());
var topoCol = ee.ImageCollection([topo]);

//Map.addLayer(topoCol)





//---Read in supporting functions: 
var func = require('users/WillHKessler/NoiseModel:Functions');

var processStates = function(state){
  var coll = ee.FeatureCollection(state['id'])
 
  //var stateName = ee.String(ee.String(state['id']).slice(ee.Number(ee.String(state['id']).rindex('/')).add(1)))
  var stateName = state['id'].slice(state['id'].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  print('Processing: ', stateName)

  //Specify parameters for zonalstats- extract mean and max values
  var params = {
    bands: [0,1], 
    bandsRename: ['DEMmean','DSMmean']
  };
  var buildings = func.zonalStats(topoCol, coll, params);
  print(buildings.size())
  }
```